# My flutter app not asking for background_loaction permission on ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, geolocation

I'm using the package [Background Location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location) to track background location in my flutter application .. here is how I edited in **info.plist**

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location to assign orders to you based on your location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location to assign orders to you based on your location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location to assign orders to you based on your location.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

And here is how am getting the location in the **dart** file :

```
  Future startLoationTracking(bool start) async {
    getDeviceLocationPermission();
    if (start) {
      var permission = await Permission.locationAlways.isGranted;
      if (!permission) {       
        var t = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
        }
        print("location started");
        if (defaultTargetPlatform != TargetPlatform.iOS){
          BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
            title: "DR Driver",
            message: "Dr driver getting your location",
            icon: "@mipmap/launcher_icon",
          );
          await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidConfiguration(1000);
        }
        await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService();
        await BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
          print("${location.latitude}");
          ApiServices().sendLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        });
    } else {
      BackgroundLocation.stopLocationService();
    }
  }
```

The app never asks for location permission.